# Using "this" in jquery after a .next() call

Tags: jquery

I am making a simple scrolling image loop, the first image goes across the screen just fine but nothing follows, am I using "this" incorrectly?
Code:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

var size = (height + width)/2;

$( document ).ready(function()
{  
    $('#pictureFrame').children('img').each(function(){$(this).css('left', '100%')});
});
window.onload = function(){startSlideshow($('#pictureFrame > img'))};
function startSlideshow(myobj) {
    $(myobj).next().animate({left: "-=" + (width + 2000)},{
        duration: 30000,
        queue: false,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete: function() {
            $(myobj).css('left', '100%')
        }
    });
    time = ($(this).width()* 10)/(width + 2000);
    setTimeout(startSlideshow($(this)),time); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pictureFrame">    
     <img class="slideshow" src="img1.jpg">
     <img class="slideshow" src="img2.jpg">
     <img class="slideshow" src="img3.jpg">
     <img class="slideshow" src="img4.jpg">    
 </div>
```

Comment: What if you use: `startSlideshow($('#pictureFrame > img:first'))`??? In your code, `$(myobj)` is all images, not only one. And you need to proxify context for the timeout. BTW, your timeout syntax is wrong here

Comment: `startSlideshow` has `window` as its `this` object. That is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I was under the impression that .next only works if called on an object containing multiple siblings. Is that wrong?

Comment: .next() search for next sibling. If none, e.g last image, empty object is returns. But there are many things wrong in your code. Use your console to debug and see what result you get compare to what result you expect

Comment: So how do I use the "next" object in refence without "this"? If I use use want to use the element in myobj.next() won't I be moving on to the next object every time I "call" it.

Comment: BUT you are calling next() on all images, not just only one at once...

Comment: `this` only gets bound if you call something as a method. If you want to reuse the object that next gives back you just need to save it in a variable. And A. Wolff is right, you should be calling `next` on a single image for what you want to do.

Comment: If I pass `$("#pictureFrame > img").first()` as the parameter on `onload`, does  `.next()` still work when called on the resulting object?

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty you should seriously starting to read DOC, especially the .next() method documentation...

Comment: It was there that I ran into the most confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this is closer to what you want:

```
window.onload = function() {
    startSlideshow($('#pictureFrame > img:first'))
};

function startSlideshow(myobj) {
    myobj.animate({left: "-=" + (width + 2000)},{
        duration: 30000,
        queue: false,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete: function() {
            $(myobj).css('left', '100%')
        }
    });
    var next = myobj.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = myobj.siblings().first();
    }
    time = ($(this).width()* 10)/(width + 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        startSlideshow(next)
    }, time);
}
```

Each call to `startSlideshow` goes to the next image in the DIV. When it runs out, it goes back to the first.

Comment: For some reason this won't loop through a second time and `setTimeout()`  won't work. the images all start moving at the same time even if I use an integer like 5 instead of `time`.

Comment: Now for some reason it just started working; however, the loop only plays once. If the callback from the first animation has not been called before an animation has been called again would that void the callback and just skip to the animation again?

Comment: I'm not really too familiar with jQuery animation, so I don't know what happens if you try to animate the same element twice concurrently. It seems like it should be some kind of conflict.